# Button can't be called from onCheckedChanged until I click Switch and click it agan to return to default state

Tags: android, android-switch

In my code I have 2 EditBox and a Switch. When I click on Switch to `true` it sets visible linear layout that contains one more EditText with image`linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

On the bottom I have a Button that does calculations of 2 cases:

1. case when Switch is `android:checked="false"`, where it just calculates values of first 2 EditBox-s
2. case when Switch is `true` and I use the third EditBox in caluculation with the first 2 Editbox-s

**PROBLEM**:
When I open the Activity and enter values in the first 2 EditBox the, and Switchs is defaultly `false`, I click on the Button to calculate and nothing happens.

But, if I just change state of Switch to `true` and to `false` again. Then I click to button and it calculates with no problem.

It completely ignores my code until I change state.

***activity_main.xml***

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <EditText
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:id="@+id/var1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:hint="Probing pulse width (s)"/>

    <EditText
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:id="@+id/var2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:hint="Pulse Repetition Time (s)"/>


    <Switch
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="Average transmitting power"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/switchID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>


<LinearLayout
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:id="@+id/hidden"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/lambda"/>

    <EditText
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:id="@+id/var3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:hint="Pulse Repetition Time (s)"/>


</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/calculate"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:text="Calculate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/rezultatID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

***MainActivity.java***

```
public class DutyCycle extends AppCompatActivity
{

String naziv;
EditText var1, var2, var3;
Button calculate;
TextView result;
Switch simpleSwitch;
double nResult, nVar1, nVar2, nVar3;
LinearLayout linearLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.duty_cycle_layout);

    naziv = getIntent().getStringExtra("formulica");

    simpleSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchID);

    var1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.var1);
    var2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.var2);
    var3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.var3);
    calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);
    result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rezultatID);

    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.hidden);
    linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    simpleSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            if(isChecked)
            {

                calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        if(!var1.getText().toString().equals("") & !var2.getText().toString().equals(""))
                        {
                              nVar1 = Double.parseDouble(var1.getText().toString());
                              nVar2 = Double.parseDouble(var2.getText().toString());
                              nVar3 = Double.parseDouble(!var3.getText().toString().equals("") ? var3.getText().toString() : "0");

                            nResult = (nVar1 / nVar2) * nVar3;


                            result.setText(String.valueOf(nResult) + " [W]");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Please fill in all fields", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .setAction("CLOSE", new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View view) {}
                                    })
                                    .setActionTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), android.R.color.holo_blue_light))
                                    .show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        if(!var1.getText().toString().equals("") & !var2.getText().toString().equals(""))
                        {
                              nVar1 = Double.parseDouble(var1.getText().toString());
                              nVar2 = Double.parseDouble(var2.getText().toString());

                            nResult = (nVar1 / nVar2) * 100;
                            result.setText(String.valueOf(nResult) + " [%]");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Please fill in all fields", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .setAction("CLOSE", new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View view) {}
                                    })
                                    .setActionTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), android.R.color.holo_blue_light))
                                    .show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

I tried with adding some boolean value in the `onCheckedChanged` so if it doesn't change state for the first time I could copy the code of `calculate.setOnClickListener` but it doesn't work.

Comment: the switch shows the linear layout? inside of the linear layout there is a calculate button? I'm confused a little. if so, take the calculate on click outside of the switch statement. you don't have to put that in there. the switch will just show/hide the layout.

Comment: Yes, I did this because I also have an ImageView that must be shown.
The calculate button is not in that LinearLayout. Only EditText and ImageView are in the LinarLayout. The problem is with the different formulas I use for that 2 cases, I am not really sure how to manage that.

Comment: it looks like the calculate button is inside of that switch code. take that out. if you have a linear layout that contains an images, thats fine. Have the switch show/hide the linear layout... and whatever is inside. when calculate gets pressed do a check to see if that linear layout is visible and if there is a value there.

Comment: It worked, thanks for clever solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [DroidDev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8200290/droidev) i managed to fix this now. I got calculate outside the onCheckedChanged and used `if(linearLayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE)` to get what formula when to use.

This is the working code now. Hope it

```
    simpleSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            if(isChecked)
            {
                linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                linearLayout.setAlpha(0.0f);
                linearLayout.animate()
                        .setDuration(500)
                        .alpha(1.0f)
                        .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                                linearLayout.animate().setListener(null);
                            }
                        });
            }
            else
            {
                linearLayout.animate()
                            .setDuration(300)
                            .alpha(0.0f)
                            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                                    linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    linearLayout.animate().setListener(null);
                                }
                            });
            }
        }
    });


    calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if(linearLayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                if (!var1.getText().toString().equals("") & !var2.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    nVar1 = Double.parseDouble(var1.getText().toString());
                    nVar2 = Double.parseDouble(var2.getText().toString());

                    nResult = (nVar1 / nVar2) * 100;
                    result.setText(String.valueOf(nResult) + " [%]");
                } else {
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Please fill in all fields", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("CLOSE", new View.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {

                                }
                            })
                            .setActionTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), android.R.color.holo_blue_light))
                            .show();
                }
            }else
            {
                if(!var1.getText().toString().equals("") & !var2.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {
                    nVar1 = Double.parseDouble(var1.getText().toString());
                    nVar2 = Double.parseDouble(var2.getText().toString());
                    nVar3 = Double.parseDouble(!var3.getText().toString().equals("") ? var3.getText().toString() : "0");

                    nResult = (nVar1 / nVar2) * nVar3;


                    result.setText(String.valueOf(nResult) + " [W]");
                }
                else
                {
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Please fill in all fields", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("CLOSE", new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {

                                }
                            })
                            .setActionTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), android.R.color.holo_blue_light))
                            .show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thats awesome! I'm glad it works for you!! Happy coding!